# How to properly implement hashing to file names so that cache-busting is automatic in Angular 7 (without any extensions)

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, angular-cli

I am trying to provide automatic cache-busting for my Angular app without using external packages. I have been researching this problem for several days and currently have `outputHashing` set to "all" and in my `app.module.ts` file I have this in my providers: `[{provide: LocationStategy, useClass: HashLocationStrategy}]`.

What I have already tried has added a # symbol in my urls, but I am not sure if this is properly cache-busting. Also, the Javascript file names do not have any hash values at the end of them and nor do my urls, they simply have the # symbol followed by the pages title.

When I run `"ng build --outputHashing=all`" the hashing values are properly applied to the end of my files, but any other command I use to run the application does not add the hash values. I need to get it to work when I add the "`--prod`" option. Any ideas?

Comment: got any solution?